# Is it possible to virtually trigger a GPIO Input pin when nothing is actually connected to it?

Tags: gpio, windows-iot, midi

I am trying to use incoming MIDI data on my Raspberry Pi 3's USB port to virtually trigger an input GPIO pin. The reason for this is as follows:

- I'm using the MIDI out port on a Behringer X-32 audio mixer to send midi data to the Pi running Windows 10 IoT Core. This is because the Pi is running a notification / HUD program for radio studio. The program can trigger display changes based on GPIO pin states, but is not built for our mixer which only has MIDI. To bridge the gap between MIDI and GPIO, my current idea is to write a program for UWP that will decode the incoming midi data and virtually trigger a GPIO input pin which the program can sense. Does anyone know if this is possible?
- If not, would I be better off doing:
  a.  writing the UWP program to actually trigger an output pin which I just jump back over to an input pin the HUD program can sense?
  or b. Decoding the MIDI data and turning it into GPIO data via an Arduino before even getting to the Pi?

Comment: It's certainly possible as I do this under Linux on the Pi quite often for testing scripts.  I wonder if the hooks would be exposed by Windows IoT though.

Comment: Thanks Joan, could you explain how you do it?

Comment: I just write to the GPIO register which sets the GPIO levels.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense. I'll give it a try!

Comment: It is difficult to follow. Do you mean trigger the GPIO on the Pi which is running this program? I do not understand why you need to "virtually" trigger GPIO ports. You may aswell virtually trigger sockets or other I/O - If you "virtually" trigger the GPIO then the actual GPIO wont trigger... so if something is attached to the GPIO then it wont trigger? Can you elaborate a bit more please. I am sure there is another way of solving this rather than "virtually" triggering stuff.